# iOS local notification when arrived at location

Tags: ios, xcode, gps, notifications, location

Hi can someone please help me?
I want to make iOS application that send local notification when I arrived at a POI or when I arrived at Latitude and Longitude that I want..
Thanks
Rani

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [`startMonitoringForRegion:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion%3adesiredAccuracy%3a) method on `CLLocationManager`. You will receive notifications when a user enters or exits each of the regions you define.

Comment: OK
but can you show me an example maybe?
or give me a good tutorial?
thanks

Comment: Take a look at the code example for onArrival in the SetSDK, https://cocoapods.org/pods/SetSDK